# Removing rounded corners from pagination

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

The following CSS removes rounded corners from the `next` button in `Bootstrap`:

```
.pagination>li:last-child>a{
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

I want to remove rounded corners from the `previous` button too. So I did this:

```
.pagination a {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;    
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Isn't it supposed to remove rounded corners from all `a` inside `.pagination`?

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, Jsfiddle and etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1 (recommended) :

```
.pagination>li:first-child>a, .pagination>li:first-child>span {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.pagination>li:last-child>a, .pagination>li:last-child>span {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

### Option 2 (recommended) :

```
.pagination>li:first-child>a, .pagination>li:first-child>span,
.pagination>li:last-child>a, .pagination>li:last-child>span {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

### Option 3 (not recommended) :

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

### Option 4 (not recommended) :

```
.pagination * {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

---

#### Note :

**I recommend AGAINST these last two options**, because `!important` ignores specificity, which should be avoided as much as you can, because it makes your code more difficult to maintain! However, it does allow you to use smaller selectors!

As [**makshh**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3258604/makshh) explains, the reason your code doesn't work, is because it doesn't have the correct specificity.

Comment: I'm tempted to use the last option, because my goal has been to reduce the amount of CSS used! Is `!important` supported in IE<8?

Comment: Yes, it is supported in IE8. If your website is not that large you can use this option. However when you have something like 10000 lines of CSS code you can forget about this `!important` rule in a month or two and it will be hard to you to debug your CSS. (notably in the case of more `!important` rules in your stylesheet).

Comment: @Yeti : `!important` should work fine in IE6, IE7 & IE8. As the amount of CSS used is so important to you, I added a fourth option that's even shorter.

Comment: Option 4 is what I'm going for! Didn't even know `*` can be used in CSS. Cool.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your selector [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). `.pagination > a` has lower specificity than `.pagination > li:first-child > a` and your code does not work.

You have two options:

First is to override all Bootstrap styles for pagination:

```
.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Second is to create your own custom class with `!important` rule to override Bootstrap styles and add this class to your div with `pagination` class:

```
.pagination-no-border-radius > li > a,
.pagination-no-border-radius > li > span {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I think I will go with the override option. Good to learn about specificity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `border radius` from all `a` try

```
.pagination a {
  border-radius: 0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to remove border-radius from pagination in Bootstrap 4 :

```
.page-item {
  &:first-child .page-link {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  &:last-child .page-link {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
}
```